# Getting Undefined constant "DB_SERVER" error when I try to connect to database from my php file

Tags: php, database

This is the code in my database functions php file. I am getting the error undefined constant. I cannot figure out how this error occurs?

```
 `<?php



    function db_connect() {  
        $database = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);  //create the object $connection  
        confirm_db_connect($database);  
        return $database; // the function returns the object $connection  
            }  
    
    function confirm_db_connect($database) {  
    
        if($database->connect_errno==0) {  
            echo "Connection to DB succeed. <br>";      
        }  
    
        if($database->connect_errno>0) {  
            $msg = "Database connection failed: ";  
            $msg .= $database->connect_error;  
            $msg .= " (" . $database->connect_errno . ")";  
            echo $msg;  
            echo "<br>";    
        }  
        }  
        ?>
```

This is how I have defined my credentials. I have created the below database with the same name in my database in localhost.

````
    <?php  
            define('SERVER_NAME','localhost');  
        define('USER_NAME','root');  
        define('PASSWORD','');  
        define('DB_NAME','rentavehicle');  

    ?>  
```
`

But still it gives me the error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "DB_SERVER" in C:\xampp\htdocs\RentAVehicle\private\database_functions.php:6 Stack trace: #0


I tried the above code and I was expecting to get the application connected to database. I have created the above database in my mySQL and I am trying to connect the above code. But it gives me the mentioned error. Changed the previous double quotes with single quotes but it did not work. I cannot figure out where the error is appearing?
````

Comment: You have defined SERVER_NAME, but then used DB_SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you do not specify the order that you are loading those scripts, but I will assume that you are loading the constants first before executing the `db_connect` function.
- Second the names of the constants do not match the expected constants on the function. You have on the function `DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME` but on the constant definition you have `SERVER_NAME, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME`.